Olympiad type geometry problem
$A$ is a given point and $P$ is any point on a given straight line. If $AQ = AP$ and $AQ$ makes a constant angle with $AP$, find the locus of $Q$.
I encountered this question in an olympiad textbook. This was in the euclidean geometry chapter. The only things done in the chapter before this are the midpoint theorem, all the properties of parallelograms, and basic geometry. Similarity and basic proportionality theorem are not done yet. Is there an elegant solution for this which only uses euclidean geometry?

Isn't it just a straight line set at the same angle to the given straight line? Or do you have the answer and just want to know how to obtain it using what you already have?

@BrianTung: Depending on how it's read I think two straight lines may be also acceptable (one positive and one negative angle) but that's how this reads to me too.

@RobinSparrow: Yeah, I thought about that, but I decided to pick the signed angle interpretation.

I don't think $Q$ is on the given line. I don't have a solution.

Are not these just two points?

Yes. Since $APQ$ is an isosceles triangle, the distance $PQ$ will always be constant.

Here is one solution, including a start relying on only very early kinds of propositions. Choose $P$ so that $AP$ is perpendicular to the line, draw a circle of radius $AP$ and mark $Q$ so that $PAQ$ subtends the given angle $\alpha$. Then the conditions are of the problem are satisfied.

Now consider the tangents at $P$ and $Q$. The tangent at $P$ is the original given line, the tangent at $Q$ will meet the tangent at $P$ at point $M$. Extend the lines $PM$ and $MQ$ by an arbitrary length to $P',Q'$. We then have that lines $PP'$ and $QQ'$ enclose angle $\alpha$ (obvious by rotation argument, you can chase angles too).
Now an initial elementary step. Mark $M'$ on $MQQ'$ so that $MQ=QM'$. Then $MAM'$ is an isosceles triangle. But M represents a qualifying position for $P$ on the original line, and $M'$ is on the same line as $MQQ'$. So now we have two solutions of the locus desired, and in our second solution we have found that $Q'$ lies on the tangent line of $Q$.
That prior elementary step isn't necessary, for by construction $PP'=QQ'$ and $PP'$ meets $QQ'$ at angle $\alpha$ (at point $M$). Therefore a rotation at $A$ by $-\alpha$ carries $Q \rightarrow P$ and line $QQ'$ must become parallel to $PP'$, but that means $QQ'$ is carried to $PP'$ and thus $AQ'=AP'$, meaning that $P'$ and $Q'$ also satisfy the conditions of the problem and Q' lies on the locus. But the length of $PP'$ was made arbitrary, so the locus of $Q'$ is the entire tangent line of $Q$.
Edit: This solution corresponds to the "single line" solution of Brian's comment. My comment about a second line also solving is if you view $\alpha$ as undirected, simply reflect everything about $AP$ and you have the second set of solutions as a mirror image.
